# '...' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value - Typescript / Javascript - import NodeJS Lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, export

I have a simple NodeJS library that exports a few constants. In that lib, we have the following setup :

the-lib/index.js

```js
  const SOME_EXAMPLE = 
    {
       'AAA': ['BBB']
     ...
    }  
  

  module.exports = {
    SomeExample: SOME_EXAMPLE
  }
```

the-lib/index.d.ts

```js
  export type SomeExample = Record<string, string[]>
```

I also have another repo, which is a NodeJS project, in which I want to use this library. As such :

service/src/index.js

```js
 import {SomeExample} from './the-lib
 console.log(SomeExample)
```

service/ts-config.json

```
... // This is just an extract to give an idea
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2022",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
...
```

When starting the service, typescript throws with `'SomeExample' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: maybe you somehow imported the type `SomeExample` instead of the object, that would cause this error because `console.log` can't print types

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's whats happening. But I guess, I don't understand why that's the case since I have exported both the object and the type. Maybe there's something wrong with the way I'm exporting or importing ?

Comment: I've never used an `index.d.ts` file so I don't know, but yeah sounds plausible. I'd look up again how other people are exporting types like this

Comment: Yea, thanks for helping. :) I've gone through these docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html but cannot seem to see the issue.

Comment: maybe instead of `export type SomeExample = Record<string, string[]>` you need to do `type SomeExample = Record<string, string[]>; module.exports = { SomeExample };`

Comment: not that it matters for your problem, but I suspect it should also be `Record<string, string[]>[]`

Comment: I would keep looking at your docs and try different combinations

Comment: Found my issue. Posted in answer. Thanks for taking a look. And good point @Matthias I have updated my original question to outline that this wasn't related. Was just trying to provide a simplified version of some complex code I had. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was misusing typescript syntax. The solution was to update my index.d.ts file as such :

```js
 export const SomeExample : Record<string, string[]>
```

I am now importing the correct value. Hope this helps someone.